# how to get NBA data

Tags: data

Hello everyone I need NBA data in my smart contract so I used some chainlink jobs but they don't provide specific data about the teams or players , is there any node that can help ? or is there another approach for this point ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SportsDataIO data source provides from ChainLink. With this data source, you can access to NBA player/team stats for a game.
You can see more how query this datasources [here](https://market.link/adapters/6420d75c-3094-4cda-aaa0-8e7317f30f03).